# Application stops When receive a notification from Firebase Notifications

Tags: android, firebase, ionic2, firebase-notifications

My application stops when you receive a notification, when the app is open, but when the application is not active, it receives 2 notifications.
Here is my `initPushNotification()`:

```
initPushNotification(){
if(!this.platform.is('cordova')){
  console.warn("Push notifications not initialized. Cordova is not available - Run in physical device");
  return;
}
const options: PushOptions = {
  android: {
    senderID:"XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    vibrate: true
  },
  ios: {
    alert: "true",
    badge: false,
    sound: "true"
  },
   windows: {}
};
const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);   
pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((data:any)=>{
  console.log("device token", data.registrationId);
  //Here I send the device_token to my firebase database.
});

pushObject.on('notification').subscribe(()=>{
    alert("new Message");
});
pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin', error)); }
```

Comment: try setting `forceShow: true` in pushOptions.

Comment: I solved the problem, uninstalled `push plugin` and worked with `cordova-plugin-firebase ` In this link is the solution.
[Solution for my problem](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/push-notifications-app-crash-when-app-is-in-foreground/86286)